# mongoDB selecting record based on two conditions

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

A sample record in my database looks like :

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "Corliss Zuk",
    "scores" : [
            {
                    "type" : "exam",
                    "score" : 87.53859552156015
            },
            {
                    "type" : "quiz",
                    "score" : 24.49132971110967
            },
            {
                    "type" : "homework",
                    "score" : 99.24881912510654
            }
    ]
```

}

I am trying to select all records that have homework scores > 90 or exam scores < 50.
My OR condition is like this:

```
 DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("scores.type", "homework").append("scores.score", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 90)); 
    DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("scores.type", "exam").append("scores.score", new BasicDBObject("$lt", 50));    
    BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
    or.add(clause1);
    or.add(clause2);
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
```

This is picking up all records where the score is > 90 or < 50 but not relating the condition that the score being examined should be either a homework score or an exam score.
I am missing a condition that will relate the scores to the type and then examine their value.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: What on earth is this code?

Comment: @Prinzhorn Java, I think

Comment: The sample record is a JSON snippet and my code is in Java

Comment: Isn't this more of a Java/driver question than MongoDB in general?

Comment: @Prinzhorn It would still end up in your `mongodb` tag list so meh but the java tags are added, was easy to edit the question.

Comment: A) Always use shell code so more people can participate in answering your question. You're asking people to puzzle through Java code now. B) Your query is broken. I'll post an answer.

Comment: For future reference please accept the first correct answer. It's rather demotivating to people if the complete answer with motivation in the correct (shell) form is not accepted and a later copy of that answer in Java. SO etiquette and all that.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet, please accept my apologies. I did try to mark your answer too as the correct one.The reason I selected attish's answer was that I wanted the solution using the Java code and not the Shell implementation. As you can see I framed the question in Java and it was reasonable to expect an answer in the same form. But again, your answer was as good as the other one and it did help.

Comment: I know but I thought it was reasonable to expect you to be able to convert a shell version to the Java equivalent and using shell/JSON syntax helps more people since the answer is language agnostic. Either way glad you got your problem solved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("scores", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("type", "homework").append("score", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 90))));
DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("scores", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("type", "exam").append("score", new BasicDBObject("$lt", 50))));
```

Use it this way.

Comment: Thanks @attish. This is exactly what I needed. I had the same query except I was prefixing 'type' with scores.type and 'score' with scores.score.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently effectively doing this :

```
find({
   $or:[
      {
         'scores.type':"exam",
         'scores.score':{
            $lt:50
         }
      },
      {
         'scores.type':"homework",
         'scores.score':{
            $gt:90
         }
      }
   ]
})
```

This is basically asking MongoDB to return any document where ANY element has a type "exam" and ANY element has a score higher than 50.0 but not necessarily the same element.

You can use the $elemMatch operator to test multiple criteria against the same element. As such the Java equivalent of this will do the trick :

```
find({
   $or:[
      {
         scores:{
            $elemMatch:{
               type:"exam",
               score:{
                  $lt:50
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         scores:{
            $elemMatch:{
               type:"homework",
               score:{
                  $gt:90
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Remon I was onto the $elemMatch operator but needed the Java equivalent of what you have given. Thanks for explaining the issue with my code clearly though.

Comment: Java equiv is simply building the above with DBObject as you were doing. It's always easier to use JSON/shell in SO for issues not specifically related to Java so more people can answer it.