# Mongodb: finding lowest element in embedded array

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, arraylist

I have a collection students look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 10,
    "name" : "Christiano Ronaldo",
    "scores" : [
            {
                    "type" : "exam",
                    "score" : 40.58945534169687
            },
            {
                    "type" : "quiz",
                    "score" : 4.30461571152303
            },
            {
                    "type" : "homework",
                    "score" : 62.36309025722009
            },
            {
                    "type" : "homework",
                    "score" : 32.1707802903173
            }
    ]
```

}

How do I find out the lowest homework? Using javadriver.

Comment: By the way, it can't be a coincedence that a number of people are struggling with problems with this particular data model. New homework assignment? ;) Example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806348/mongodb-selecting-record-based-on-two-conditions

Comment: Most of the newbies are really struggling. yes it's an assignment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't with normal querying. You always query for full documents rather than embedded elements within that document. If you make seperate documents for each score, e.g :

```
{
    "_id" : 10,
    "name" : "Christiano Ronaldo",
    "type" : "exam",
    "score" : 40.58945534169687
}
```

You can search highest/lowest exam score for Christiano Ronaldo. Note that the MongoDB Aggregation Framework can be used to answer your question but I'm going to assume that's out of scope here.

Also note that your schema is very problematic. There is no way to query a specific "homework" score with this schema. I would denormalize here and use a document per score.

Comment: for solving the assignment it wouldn't be a good idea to denormalize the schema because to verify my answer I have to run a specific aggregate function on my previous result.

Comment: Can you add to your original question what the expected result should be? You say "find lowest homework" but what does that mean? The document with the lowest homework in the entire collection or the array element with the lowest homework within a document?

Comment: Couldn't you use the $elemMatch to get type:'homework' ? eg from shell: db.students.find({}, {scores:{$elemMatch:{type:'homework'}}})